# Deleting table rows in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with a function in javascript and can't figure out why.  It's really quite straight forward.  I'm trying to delete all the rows in a html table. so I wrote:

```
function delete_gameboard(){
   var table = document.getElementById("gameboard");
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      table.deleteRow(i);
   }
}
```

Yet, it'll only delete half of them.  Can anyone see what's causing this strange behavior?

Comment: Probably, when you delete a row, the indexes of the rows go down. Try: `table.deleteRow(0);`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because when you delete the first row, the second row will become the first, it's dynamic.

You could do like:

```
while(table.rows.length > 0) {
  table.deleteRow(0);
}
```

Comment: Helps to visualize these things or walk through it diagrammatically in pseudo code :) But yeah, that's an oversight one tends not to make more than once!

Answer (score 5):

Consider this:

```
index 0:  row #1
index 1:  row #2
index 2:  row #3
index 3:  row #4
index 4:  row #5
```

you delete index #2 (row #3), so the DOM engine adjusts the index keys and you end up with:

```
index 0:  row #1
index 1:  row #2
index 2:  row #4   <---hey! index #2 is still there
index 3:  row #5
```

You're basically digging a hole in the spot where you're standing, so as you dig deeper, you naturally sink deeper and never see any progress... until you run out of rows to delete in the table.

Answer (score 4):

```
function delete_gameboard(){
var table = document.getElementById("gameboard");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for (var i=rowcount-1; i >=0; i--) {
    table.deleteRow(i);
}
}
```

The index of the row changes when you delete it. Use a reverse loop. This will also be helpful if you are using any condition to delete rows. If you are deleting all rows,use the following

```
while(table.rows.length) {
  table.deleteRow(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you delete the first row, the second row becomes the new first row.

I prefer to do this:

```
while(table.rows[0]) table.deleteRow(0);
```

Comment: really your method is very good but at the both side if "1" put then without header clean the table data.

Answer (score 3):

You could just go:

```
    document.getElementById("gameboard").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: I found rows added by javascript were not accessible by the OP's method. Solved my problem by setting the innerHTML="" instead of deleting rows via the dom. Haven't tested this properly,

Comment: If deleting rows is all that matters then this method is efficiently the best. It didn't even occur to me at first. LOL.

Answer (score 2):

The `table` rows is live, that is if you delete row 0 then the next row becomes row 0, just constantly delete row 0

```
function delete_gameboard(){
    var table = document.getElementById("gameboard");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i=0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        table.deleteRow(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function delRow()
  {
    var current = window.event.srcElement;
    //here we will delete the line
    while ( (current = current.parentElement)  && current.tagName !="TR");
    current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using JQuery in your code then the easiest way to delete the rows is using the following code:

```
$('#myTable tbody').html('');
```